# loading an logo image in to an UIImage from Parse.com

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimage, parse-platform

i am trying to load a Logo image in to a UiImage the logo image is in parse but not sure how to load it in to the viewcontroller

.h file

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *Logo;
```

.m File

```
self.Logo.image = [self.exam objectForKey:@"Logo"];
```

it throws the following error

-[PFFile size]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

so i have to use PFfile but not sure how to format it i have searched but most examples have a query invoiled and i dont need the query as the data is there ready in

```
self.exam objectForKey:@"Logo"
```

now added

```
[self.exam objectForKey:@"Logo"];
self.Logo.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData: [self.exam objectForKey:@"Logo"]];
```

but get the following error the image is a .png

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[PFFile length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

NSlog is showing the file as

```
Logo = "<PFFile: 0x111875190>";
```

Comment: You should use [self.exam objectForKey:@"Logo"].getData but not [self.exam objectForKey:@"Logo"]

Comment: when i try that i get property not found on object of type 'id'

Comment: then call getter method: [[self.exam objectForKey:@"Logo"] getData]

Comment: that compiled but when i click in to view controller ..... 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[PFFile length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10d93d4a0'

Comment: Thats because you use PFFile instead of NSData.

Comment: thats its i just put it in the wrong place. thanks

Comment: Have you resolved your issue?

Comment: yes im not sure how to show as solved as your comments dont have a tick next to them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[self.exam objectForKey:@"Logo"];
```

Is instance of class `PFFile` but not `UIImage`.
You should convert it. You can try following:

```
self.Logo.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData: [[self.exam objectForKey:@"Logo"] getData]];
```

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[PFFile length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10dc58e20

Comment: Did you add [self.exam objectForKey:@"Logo"].getData?

Comment: Scrap That The View Controller loads but no logo image

Comment: Probably data is nil. You should check it. Also you can use async method - (void)getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:(PFDataResultBlock)block

Comment: I saw it. But what is the reason?

Answer (score 0):

`PFFile` is a subclass of `NSObject`, thus the `UIImage`' `length` method cannot be called, resulting to your NSInvalidArgumentException.

You should use an `PFImageView` instead of your UIImageView.

.h file

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet PFImageView *Logo;
```

.m file

```
self.Logo.file = [self.exam objectForKey:@"Logo"];
[self.Logo.loadInBackground];
```

A `loadInBackground:` method with completion block is also available.